# JSON serialize Python Enum object

Tags: python, json

While serializing Enum object to JSON using json.dumps(...), python will throw following error:

```
>>> class E(enum.Enum):
...     A=0
...     B=1
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(E.A)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\guptaaman\Miniconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "C:\Users\guptaaman\Miniconda3\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Users\guptaaman\Miniconda3\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Users\guptaaman\Miniconda3\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type E is not JSON serializable
```

How to make Enum object JSON serializable?

Comment: What do you expect the result to be?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can make the class which is inheriting Enum to also inherit str class as following:

```
>>> class E(str, enum.Enum):
...     A="0"
...     B="1"
...
>>> json.dumps(E.A)
'"0"'
```

Reference: https://hultner.se/quickbits/2018-03-12-python-json-serializable-enum.html

Answer (score 4):

Use `enum.IntEnum` instead of `enum.Enum` and it will be serialized as an integer automatically.